# Mac Microsoft Outlook 2011+ Aggressive Auto Config

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

Outlook has an annoying habit of autodiscovering (aggressively) the internal server and switching your configuration, no matter how many times you manually set it.
This script will switch off autodiscover so that it will keep whatever manual configuration you give it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is change INSERT_ACCOUNT_NAME to the name of the account you want this to apply to.
To reenable autodiscover, just change 'false' to 'true' and run the script again.
Once you modify below, use the AppleScript Editor to create an .app and you can just double click while you have Outlook open.

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set background autodiscover of exchange account "INSERT_ACCOUNT_NAME" to false

end tell
```